# Hiding a stage on the same Mac OS without external monitor during live presentation

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, screen-capture

I finally got my project on how to integrate Auth0 APIs into my ASP.NET MVC web app, save their token in an SQL Server distributed cache in Docker on a MacBook.
So **I wanted to finally show the audience live** how this can be achieved and why it's helpful.

**The problem is** I only have a MacBook Air M1 to demo my code on and noticed one presenter has  2 Windows laptops. One has his code to show what he's doing in Visual Studio which renders the program to a browser while the other dual-linked laptop has the cheat sheet that he hides from everyone.

Is it possible I could use any special software to hide certain stages of my display from the audience containing the cheat sheet from my website? It saves buying a new laptop or tablet just for one purpose.

Comment: Not sure if that's possible yet but it was announced at WWDC23 that you could share a specific window for a meeting, keeping some "cheat sheets" next to it without them being seen.

Comment: I don't see how the WWDC announcement allows sharing without another Mac / computer to receive the image - so we will have to see - managing a demo is hard and paper notes is something I should add to my answer as an edit. The KISS aspect of have your notes separate from the thing you are showing off is time tested and proven to work with both our brains and our tooling.

Comment: @bmike For example, with the announced feature, you could make a Zoom meeting while sharing only one window.

Comment: Understood @Thinkr - that exists already for Zoom for years no need for any new Apple OS feature - what is missing is redacting / limiting what the Mac shares to an external display here - the OP has their device connected to an external display unless they edit in that they have an AirPlay receiver or are willing to send the entire presentation to a network device - we can't assume anything at this point...

Comment: @bmike Oh. Alright. I must've misunderstood the question then. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keynote is one app that will provide private presenter notes to you but show  a presentation on the remote screen. Powerpoint is in the same vein and neither will work for live screen mirroring.

I don't see an easy way to do this in software since you're using the OS to mirror and not running a second computer to control / crop things. Unless there's software someone knows for this - you'll want to use a second computer and OBS to control the mixing and live presentation or just have a second computer / iPad / iPhone for the presenter notes. All of iOS devices will run a display and work well for your specific needs and constraint that you want everything to work from one computer.

Adding hardware is the practical way to achieve exactly what you seek with existing tech and software that's open source / low cost.

Comment: Google Slides also does this.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up being able to convince my workplace to allow me to have a spare laptop without corporate info so it does not become a security risk.

I did this by explaining why I need it. Told them I do not make any money from it and do it purely for becoming better.

I was advised to tell them when I will give it back. I have negotiated a 2-month loan for it until then.

Was able to install Logitech Options+ on it with a nonactivated version of Windows 10 Pro to allow data to be copied between computers with my Logitech keyboard and mouse combo.